# Optional Log File for Batch File?

Tags: user-interface, logging, windows-xp, batch-file, optional-parameters

I have a Batch Interface I've created for a DOS program I'm using and I want to add an Option at the End to save the Output of the Batch File to a File, BUT I don't want the Log to be created unless the user says Yes at the END of the Batch File. So Far the Only way I've found to Optionally create a Log file is to Launch the Batch file like this "something.bat >output.txt" BUT that's at the Beginning BEFORE the Batch is even started which is NOT what I want. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Write your log file to a temporary file, created below the %TEMP% folder. When you ask the user at the end of your program if he wants to keep it, copy your temporary file to the place where the user expects it. Otherwise remove the log file.

Comment: How do I create a Log file without having to launch the Batch like this:"example.bat>%TEMP%\log.txt"?

Comment: Create a wrapper script *exampleWrapper.bat* which calls example.bat >%TEMP%\log.txt" internally, asks the user if he wants to keep the log etc. The wrapper script itself will be called without output redirection. Alternatively, add output redirection to every command inside *example.bat* except the last ones where the user is questioned.